# Do They Make Two-Panel "Barn Door" Interior Doors, with Both Panels Sliding to One Side?

Tags: doors, interior

I have a closet that contains my washer and dryer, with a 60" wide x 80" high opening. Right now, that closet has bi-fold doors, but they are in poor shape, and I am looking to replace them.

The closet is in a hallway, not a room, and with the bi-fold doors open, they block a good chunk of the hallway width. So, I was interested in perhaps switching to "barn door" style interior doors.

However, I only have 30" space on the left and 8" space on the right before I encounter other doors. The two-panel barn doors that I have seen open one panel to each side on a single track. That would block another door on the right when the right-side panel is open.

Do they make this style of door, where via two tracks (or some other system) both panels open to one side? If so, then perhaps I could rig up two 30"x80" panels and a ~90" track, where both panels could slide to the left. This would not interfere with any other doors, and I could have the full 60" opening available (or thereabouts).

Comment: Yes use two tracks and the doors can go to the same side, but you need sufficient depth for both doors.

Comment: Do the tracks come with standoffs or something that allow for adjustable depth? Or would I have to come up with my own means of having one track be further out than the other?

Comment: Not sure what they offer in your locality - you have to look. But some I saw had single or twin brackets...

Comment: Yeah, OK, I now see that I need to be searching on "bypass" for a two-door, single-side solution. Thanks!

Comment: I searched for "bypass barn doors" and found this hardware kit -  https://www.wayfair.com/home-improvement/pdp/homacer-straight-strap-bypass-barn-door-hardware-kit-w001424135.html

Comment: Barn doors are a bunch of hardware parts you assemble, if you would like them to go separate directions yes it would be easy but I would purchase a single top rail, this is very common on barns. the lighter duty hardware like for horse or livestock stalls is easy to build what you want at much cheaper that the “show room” cost.